# ¿Qué verbo se usa con la palabra "reflejo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Cuál es el verbo más apropiado para usar con el sustantivo "reflejo" (en el [significado número 7 de la RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=b9wBCSWBiDXX2fNO1msx))?

> Esto me *provoca* el reflejo vomitivo.
>
> Esto me *causa* el reflejo vomitivo.
>
> Esto me *llama* el reflejo vomitivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haciendo una búsqueda en Google obtenemos los siguientes resultados:

- *provocar el reflejo* da 52 400 resultados, de los que todos los primeros tienen el sentido buscado
- *causar el reflejo* da 14 100 resultados, en algunos de los cuales la palabra *reflejo* se refiere a *reflejo óptico*
- *llamar el reflejo* (expresión que no había oído antes) da 26 400 resultados, pero el verbo *llamar* siempre tiene el sentido de *denominar* (*lo que se ha dado en llamar el reflejo condicionado*, por ejemplo)

Esto coincide con mi propia experiencia como hispanohablante en España: es más habitual el uso del verbo *provocar* en este caso, aunque *causar* tampoco sería incorrecto. En cambio, *llamar* no se usa con este sentido.

Comment: Provocar y causar pueden ser utilizados, en particular para reflejo nunca lo vi acompañado del verbo llamar. Otra forma que agregaría es dar, "comer esto me da reflejo vomitivo".

Comment: @Zukki No creo que *dar* sea un buen verbo en este caso. Podríamos decir *me da arcadas*, *me da náuseas* o *me da ganas de vomitar*, pero no *me da reflejo vomitivo*.

Answer (score 2):

No creo que hayas captado bien el 7º significado de reflejo... Un reflejo es una reacción simple e instantánea, como el apartarse bruscamente cuando tocas algo que quema. Por esa razón, no están explicitados los distintos tipos de reflejos. Un *reflejo vomitivo* es una construcción que no existe (al menos en España y en el ámbito normal, no sé si se usará en el ámbito médico). Opino que es más adecuado decir simplemente *vómito* o, si acaso, *reacción de vómito*.

En cualquier caso, para referirse a un reflejo, o un *acto reflejo*, tal como apartarse al quemarse, lo más adecuado sería *generar* o *provocar*, aunque también *causar* puede utilizarse. Respecto a *llamar*, nunca lo había oído, pero no descarto que se use en otros países.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo diría de la siguiente forma:

> Esto me genera el reflejo vomitivo.

"genera el reflejo" tiene  1,460,000 resultados donde están incluidos los otros significados de la palabra, sin embargo, creo que una palabra polisémica puede utilizar el mismo verbo y el significado tomado dependerá más del contexto que del verbo que se uttilice.